# prestashop import sub categories CSV

Tags: csv, prestashop

How can i import sub-categories in Prestashop with a CSV file?? I can't find anything good on google, and i'm already trying the whole day.

I've tried:

```
Name*
hardware,"graphics cards"
hardware,printers
hardware,monitors
hardware,speakers
hardware,keyboards
hardware,mice
```

And:

```
Name*
hardware
hardware,"graphics cards"
hardware,printers
hardware,monitors
hardware,speakers
hardware,keyboards
hardware,mice
```

But nothing seems to work? Hardware is the main category and the others the sub categories. 
I can import normal categories, and customers, etc i only have trouble with sub categories.

Answer (score 1):

One problem might be the Field separator. Default in the prestashop import is ; you should replace it with , 
Or replace the comma in your csv with ;